# Raining and independence on the weekend

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, random-variables, expected-value, independence

Say there is a $20$ percent chance of rain on Saturday, $30$ percent chance of rain on Sunday. If the two events are independent of each other, then the chance of it raining on at least one of the days is$$.2 + .3 - (.2)(.3) = .44.$$However, if I'm told that raining on Saturday makes it more likely to rain on Sunday, will the probability go up or down that it will rain on at least one day? I'm not sure how to answer this question, hence asking here.

Comment: Why not design a model?  Let $0=$ no rain and $1=$ rain and define $p_{ij}$ to be the probability that you'll be in state $j$ tomorrow given you are in state $i$ today.  Adjust to fit the given numbers.  An example should provide a lot of clarity.

Comment: For a hand waving argument, note that it's unlikely that it is raining on Saturday and it must be the case that not-raining increases the chance of not-raining on Sunday, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A="it rains on Saturday", B="it rains on Sunday".

You are asked P(A or B)=P(A)+P(B)- P(A and B)

The last term can be written as
P(A and B)=P(B|A) P(A)
If A and B are independent, then P(B|A)=P(B).
However, if rain on Saturday makes rain on Sunday more likely, then P(B|A)>P(B), and hence P(A or B) will decrease, as

P(A or B)=P(A)(1-P(B|A))+P(B)

and P(A) and P(B) remained constant.